# How to configure a trigger for a Google AppScript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I've found some Google AppScript code I'd like to mash-up which plugs into the Twitter API and e-mails me certain tweets: http://blog.programmableweb.com/2010/10/01/convert-tweets-to-emails-with-google-appsscript/

Everything makes sense except the finally instruction "configure a trigger in the Google AppsScript editor."

I'm not entirely sure what that means. Can I just put something like this to run the script every minute?

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  twitter2email();
}, 60000);
```

Any help appreciated, I'm sure there's a really simple answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the script editor, you'll notice there is a Menu item called "Triggers" in the main menu bar. If you choose the "Current Triggers" option from the "Triggers" drop down menu, you'll have the option of adding a new trigger and specifying the parameters.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't even think of looking at the menu.

Comment: No, genuine tunnel vision + stupidity. I was too busy looking at the code to even notice the menus :p